# Как подключить счётчик к соответствующему input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть следующая страница. В ней есть 2 поля `input`. К каждому из них прикручен своеобразный счётчик: 2 кнопки (`button`): плюс и минус. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `plus` число в соответствующем `input` увеличивалось, а при нажатии на `minus` - уменьшалось.

```
<div class="make_an_order">
  <form action="*">

      <div class="order_block">

          <div class="options">
              <span class="product"></span>
              <span class="price"><span class="value">39 грн</span> <span class="note">(за 12 кг )</span></span>
              <span class="to_order">заказать <span class="note">(минимум: 12 кг)</span></span>
          </div>

          <div class="numerator">
              <input name="count" class="field" type="number" value="12"><span class="measure">кг</span>
              <button type="button" class="minus" onclick="inc(-1)"><span class="flaticon-minus-sign-of-a-line-in-horizontal-position"></span></button>
              <button type="button" class="plus" onclick="inc(1)"><span class="flaticon-add"></span></button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <br>  

      <div class="order_block">

          <div class="options">
              <span class="product"></span>
              <span class="price"><span class="value">39 грн</span> <span class="note">(за 1 аршин )</span></span>
              <span class="to_order">заказать <span class="note">(минимум: 1 аршин)</span></span>
          </div>

          <div class="numerator">
              <input name="count" class="field" type="number" value="1"><span class="measure">аршин</span>
              <button type="button" class="minus" onclick="inc(-1)"><span class="flaticon-minus-sign-of-a-line-in-horizontal-position"></span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="plus" onclick="inc(1)"><span class="flaticon-add"></span></button>
          </div>
      </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Пробовал сделать через `onclick` - но никак не удаётся задать/вытащить нужный мне `input`

```
function inc(N) {
  console.log($(this).parent( ".numerator").value)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, например, берем родителя при помощи `.parentNode` и потом при помощи [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) можно найти сам `<input>`

```
function inc(el, v){
  let i = el.parentNode.querySelector('input');
  i.value = v + +i.value;
}
```

```js
function inc(el, v){
  let i = el.parentNode.querySelector('input');
  i.value = v + +i.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="make_an_order">
  <form action="*">
      <div class="order_block">
          <div class="options">
              <span class="product"></span>
              <span class="price"><span class="value">39 грн</span> <span class="note">(за 12 кг )</span></span>
              <span class="to_order">заказать <span class="note">(минимум: 12 кг)</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="numerator">
              <input name="count" class="field" type="number" value="12"><span class="measure">кг</span>
              <button type="button" class="minus" onclick="inc(this,-1)"><span class="flaticon-minus-sign-of-a-line-in-horizontal-position"></span></button>
              <button type="button" class="plus" onclick="inc(this,1)"><span class="flaticon-add"></span></button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <br>  
      <div class="order_block">
          <div class="options">
              <span class="product"></span>
              <span class="price"><span class="value">39 грн</span> <span class="note">(за 1 аршин )</span></span>
              <span class="to_order">заказать <span class="note">(минимум: 1 аршин)</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="numerator">
              <input name="count" class="field" type="number" value="1"><span class="measure">аршин</span>
              <button type="button" class="minus" onclick="inc(this, -1)"><span class="flaticon-minus-sign-of-a-line-in-horizontal-position"></span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="plus" onclick="inc(this,1)"><span class="flaticon-add"></span></button>
          </div>
      </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

---

Жуквери версия:

```
function inc(el, v) {
  let i = $(el.parentNode).find("input");
  i.val(+i.val() + v);
}
```

```js
function inc(el, v) {
  let i = $(el.parentNode).find("input");
  i.val(+i.val() + v);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="make_an_order">
  <form action="*">
      <div class="order_block">
          <div class="options">
              <span class="product"></span>
              <span class="price"><span class="value">39 грн</span> <span class="note">(за 12 кг )</span></span>
              <span class="to_order">заказать <span class="note">(минимум: 12 кг)</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="numerator">
              <input name="count" class="field" type="number" value="12"><span class="measure">кг</span>
              <button type="button" class="minus" onclick="inc(this,-1)"><span class="flaticon-minus-sign-of-a-line-in-horizontal-position"></span></button>
              <button type="button" class="plus" onclick="inc(this,1)"><span class="flaticon-add"></span></button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <br>  
      <div class="order_block">
          <div class="options">
              <span class="product"></span>
              <span class="price"><span class="value">39 грн</span> <span class="note">(за 1 аршин )</span></span>
              <span class="to_order">заказать <span class="note">(минимум: 1 аршин)</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="numerator">
              <input name="count" class="field" type="number" value="1"><span class="measure">аршин</span>
              <button type="button" class="minus" onclick="inc(this, -1)"><span class="flaticon-minus-sign-of-a-line-in-horizontal-position"></span>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="plus" onclick="inc(this,1)"><span class="flaticon-add"></span></button>
          </div>
      </div>

  </form>
</div>
```